# Migrate Fabric's Crashlystic data to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

As the title, I need to migrate all existing data from Fabric's Crashlytics to Firebase.

The problem here is after migrating, If I remove fabric key in AndroidManifest, My app can't push the crash report to firebase's Crashlytics anymore.
But when I create Firebase's Crashlytics from the beginning (without Fabric migrate) They recommend me to remove existing Fabric key to make it work.

Is it ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.  Yes, now is a good time to start linking and migrating to Firebase.

Comment: Can you explain more detail? So how can I have that kind of data without app linking?

Comment: If you're currently using Crashlytics via Fabric, then data will flow there. If you're using Firebase Crashlytics, then data would show up there.

Comment: Oh got it. At this moment, I'm linking Fabric with Firebase, and the data shows up in both place. What happens if one day Fabric shut down its Crashlytics service, will my crash report continues to show up on Firebase with current configuration?

Comment: Gotcha, if you're doing a combined setup, then you would see data in both places. Given your current configuration it sounds like you would be all set.

Comment: I have also done the linking but now I want to turn off Fabric, and removing the meta-data from the Manifest doesn't do the thing. How can I get the reports only on Fabric?

Comment: After migration completed application stop sending the crash report to fabric and firebase crashlytics dashboard

Comment: Contact the support folks if you have issues post-migration as they can dig deeper into this.