# How to migrate from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io

I have an app that logs crashes and non-fatals to Fabric Crashlytics and uses Firebase Analytics to log analytics events.

I want to migrate from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics. In addition I want to save historical data from Fabric during the migration.

When I try to do it with provided mechanism of Firebase Migration (https://fabric.io/firebase_migration/apps) I cannot do it in a way I want to. In particular, I cannot provide existent Firebase project ID for migration. I see error:

[image: Cannot migrate to existent project]

1. So how can I do migrate properly?
2. I found some statements from Fabric team members (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49734863/4312184) that migration process is not ready for saving historical data. But maybe it is ready now?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx43Yck94dU

Comment: @Nudge thanks for the link! But unfortunately it has no answers to my questions - neither about migrating from Fabric to existent project to Firebase nor about saving historical data during migration.

Comment: try this ,https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-crashlytics-to-the-firebase-console-5e05b6ff8c12

Comment: @chetanmahajan Yeah, I saw this article before publishing the question. And sadly it not helps in described situation

Comment: Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. It looks like you're going through the migration flow and creating a new project. If you're logged in from the Migration page with the same email address that you use in Firebase, then you should see your Firebase projects below creating a new project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What happened when you migrated?

For the apps that you linked, your Crashlytics data now appears in the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/crashlytics) (in the Firebase console). The linking process does not involve any changes to the Crashlytics SDK or your Fabric API key.

Note that in the coming months, we'll release Firebase-specific Crashlytics SDKs for iOS and for Android, as well as offer further upgrade instructions. So for now, if you migrated an iOS and Android app:

- Do not change how you use the Crashlytics SDK because the iOS and Android SDKs haven't changed.
- Do not change or remove your Fabric API key.

Note: For migrating Unity apps to Firebase, follow the [Unity migration instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migrate-from-fabric) and review the [Unity API changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/api-changes).

#### Discover Firebase Crashlytics

Find all your Crashlytics data in the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/crashlytics) (in the Firebase console).

Important: To view crash-free users metrics, you need [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking#start-using-analytics) in your app.

Firebase Crashlytics offers several new features:

- [Customize your velocity alerts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/velocity-alerts).
- Use Google Analytics breadcrumbs (requires [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking#start-using-analytics)).
- [Export your Crashlytics data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export), then analyze it using BigQuery and the Crashlytics Data Studio template.
- New integrations (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/integrations), including a [Jira integration](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9118259) that enables you to link Crashlytics issues with Jira issues from the Firebase console.

#### Start using Google Analytics

[Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics) is Firebase's analytics engine and gives you access to powerful insights into your data.

**Install the Google Analytics SDK**

Visit the Google Analytics documentation to learn how to install and initialize the SDK in your [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=ios), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android), or [Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start) app.

Note: After you initialize the Google Analytics SDK in your app, there can be a delay of a few hours before data appears in the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard.

**How Google Analytics helps Crashlytics**

Google Analytics unlocks valuable capabilities and features that you were already using in Fabric:

- [Monitor your Latest Release status.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking#latest-release)
- [Use Google Analytics events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking#replace-answers) like you used Fabric's Answers.
- Track your app's crash-free users metrics in the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/crashlytics).
- Set custom alerts for your app's stability with [velocity alerts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/velocity-alerts).

Note: Firebase can only use analytics data collected by Google Analytics. So, for your migrated apps, your historical analytics data (from Fabric Answers) cannot migrate to Firebase. This means that, unlike your crash data, your analytics data will start from a blank slate and the Firebase console will only show data collected after installing and initializing the Google Analytics SDK.

**Monitor your Latest Release**

With Google Analytics initialized in your app, you can monitor the stability and metrics of your current builds in the Latest Release page (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/analytics/latestrelease) in the Firebase console.

Access the Latest Release page a couple different ways:

- In your Firebase Crashlytics dashboard (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/crashlytics), click the link in the Event trends card.
- In the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), go to the Analytics section in the left navigation pane, then click Latest Release.

**Use Events rather than Answers**

Google Analytics lets you set custom and predefined events, similar to Fabric's Answers.

- To learn how to set up events using Firebase, visit the Google Analytics documentation for your platform ([iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events), or [Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/events)).
- To learn how to convert your existing Answers events to Google Analytics events, visit the [Fabric Analytics page](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/examples/firebase/index.html#events).

Important: After you instrument Google Analytics events, we recommend removing Answers events from your app's code.

#### Configure your notification settings

Now that you've migrated to Firebase, you will start getting emails from both Firebase and Fabric.

You can configure your notifications settings:

- **For Firebase** — Configure your Firebase notifications and integrations in the Firebase console:

  - For notifications, manage your Firebase alert subscriptions for Crashlytics via *Alerts* -> *Alert Settings* (click the bell icon in the top-right corner of the Firebase console).
  - For integrations, visit *Project settings* -> *Integrations (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/integrations)* to set up notifications for Jira, Slack, and PagerDuty.
- **For Fabric** — Configure your Fabric notifications in [Fabric's settings page](https://fabric.io/settings/notifications) (https://fabric.io/settings/notifications):

  **Note:** <s>Firebase Crashlytics will use Fabric per [get.fabric.io/roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) only until March 31, 2020.</s> Migrate your apps to Firebase to take advantage of the latest products and features there.

  - Modify the settings for your Fabric notifications so that you're not receiving duplicate emails from both Firebase and Fabric.

#### Invite your team members

Now that you've migrated to Firebase, invite your team so that they can start using Firebase and access your migrated app in the Firebase console.

- **From the Firebase console** — Visit *Project settings* -> *Users & permissions (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/iam)* to add teammates as members of your Firebase project.
- **From the Fabric site** — Visit the [invite page](https://fabric.io/firebase_migration/invite) (https://fabric.io/firebase_migration/invite) in the Fabric migration dashboard to invite your teammates to your migrated apps. With just one click, you can add all teammates associated with your app to your Firebase project.

Note: Using the one-click invite button on Fabric's migration dashboard assigns the [Editor role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles) to all invited members.

<sub>**Source:** [Migration steps after linking from Fabric](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking)</sub>

Comment: Firebase says we need to add Analytics to get full crash logs. My app was not there on Firebase until now, so do i need to add Analytics to my app now ?. To do that I'll have to add google-service.json file too , right ?

Comment: [Adding Google Analytics for Firebase to an instant app project](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/guides/analytics#adding_to_an_instant_app_project) *1. Add the Firebase SDK to your app by following the instructions described in the Getting started guide for Google Analytics for Firebase. 2. Use the latest version of the google-services plugin. 3. Place the google-services.json file in each module...*

Comment: Is it required to add Firebase SDK ? They've clearly mentioned Crashlytics works with Fabric SDK. All i want to know is, do we need to add Analytics for Crashlytics to work properly ?

Comment: thanks for the help. I've asked the same question here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59623929/5742437

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics uses Fabric per [get.fabric.io/roadmap](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap) only until March 31.

Comment: Yes. I read that. Probably need to add Firebase to my apps. Any idea what will happen to those apps which don't update ?

Comment: If you add does not work if you don't add does not work! Better is Sentry or bugsnag!

Comment: @karel I have used fabric before 2 years. Now again i am going to update the app version from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2. Now the fabric dashboard is not there. So I have removed the fabric integrations in my code and can i integrate firebase? What is the good practice now.

Comment: @sejn It is a topic of general interest. Please ask a separate question at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Asked a new question. Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672775/what-is-best-way-of-migrating-the-fabric-to-crashlytics-now-after-may-2020-all