# Android Firebase Crashlytics displays no crashes for Internal Test Track

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have firebase crashlytics integrated on a new android app and its currently deployed on internal test track only. I see the internal version tags show in crashlytics but I see no crashes for that those versions.

Are crashlytics logs not available for internal test track? Would they work for alpha (closed) test track?

`AndroidManifest.xml` has:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"  
 android:value="false" />
```

Initializing as:

```
Fabric.with(Fabric.Builder(this)
                    .kits(Crashlytics(), CrashlyticsNdk())
                    .build())
```

in the `Application` subclass.

The setup was done following the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

Also added:

`implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5'`
to the `build.gradle` for `crashlytics ndk` support. (Assuming the symbols are uploaded automatically with cmake build)

Comment: Can you post your current implementation of Crashlytics

Comment: Currently Fabric is deprecated, so you need another way to initialize Crashlytics. [Migrate your apps to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656828/) to take advantage of the latest products and features there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Fabric was deprecated.

So you need to other way to initialize Crashlytics.

I added a link that would help.

It shows the way to test Crashlytics internally with adb.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=1&platform=android