# Firebase Analytics required for Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, crashlytics-android

I've migrated my apps from Fabric to Firebase. All the apps are now visible in Firebase.
My apps don't have Firebase integrated. As per the integration doc, app will still report crashes without Firebase SDK(only need Fabric SDK).

What i'm confused about is, do i need to add Firebase Analytics to get proper crash logs ?
Because i forced a crash using below code(provided by [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?authuser=1&platform=android#force_a_crash_to_test_your_implementation)) but it didn't record in Firebase but recorded in Fabric.

```
Button crashButton = new Button(this);
crashButton.setText("Crash!");
crashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Crashlytics.getInstance().crash(); // Force a crash
    }
});

addContentView(crashButton, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Actually Firebase Crashlytics use *fabric*

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman as per https://get.fabric.io/roadmap only till 31st March.

Comment: Firebase Analytics is not required to use Crashlytics, but if you use both you will get better crash reports (since it combines the information from both). The problem is likely coming from somewhere else, although I can't say where based on the information provided. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Analytics is not required to use Crashlytics, but if you use both you will get better crash reports (since it combines the information from both). The problem is likely coming from somewhere else, although I can't say where based on the information provided. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Do you know what will happen after 31st March when Fabric stops ? Will they ask us to add Firebase to app ?

Comment: Please be clearer in your questions. Firebase is a platform of 18 products at last count, Crashlytics being one of them. But if you're wondering that you'll be required to add Firebase's Analytics in order to use Crashlytics, there are no plans for that at the moment.