# What is best way of migrating the Fabric to crashlytics now (After may 2020, all data and dashboards are disappeared)

Tags: android, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have used Fabric before 2 years.Now I need to migrate to firebase. Here what is the good way to proceed? Shall I remove all fabric related integrations and add firebase as new integration.

Or

Shall I need to add the firebase with the existing fabric account?

Any best practices?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656828/2068732

Comment: @matdev I have checked that and comment there too. The above thread shows the migration process when the fabric dashboard is alive. But now it not possible to see the dashboard or data according to the fabric team

Comment: This should help you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here -

If you missed the migration window to move from Fabric to Firebase, the best way forward is to set up a new Firebase project, add your desired apps to your Firebase project, and then [follow the Crashlytics onboarding instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) to get Firebase Crashlytics working. The Firebase Crashlytics SDK is now the main supported Crashlytics SDK, and the old Fabric SDK will no longer report crashes past November 15th, as Misha noted.

Once you've been able to verify that a test crash has come through to your dashboard, you should be all set to include it in a live version that goes out to your users.

Answer (score 0):

In **Fabric** you easily migrate your existing projects to **Firebase** account. Migration is just a click of a button in Fabrics web page.

**Next thing is integration of SDK into project.**

You can leave old Fabric SDK for now. It will continue reporting your app's crashes until [**November 15, 2020**](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/06/crashlytics-sdk-now-available.html).

But after November 15 you will need [to remove Fabrics sdk and install Firebase.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android)