# When should we start moving Fabric's Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, crashlytics

I've an IOS app which is using Fabric Crashlytics. As you know:

> The Fabric iOS and Android mobile apps will be sunset on November 30, 2018.

So I'm trying to migrate all existing data from Fabric's Crashlytics to Firebase. But I've seen this topic [Migrate Fabric's Crashlystic data to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725108/migrate-fabrics-crashlystic-data-to-firebase), and **Mike from Fabric recommended that we should not yet migrate now**.

Here is the question:

At this moment, I'm linking Fabric with Firebase, and the data shows up in both place. What happens if one day Fabric shut down its Crashlytics service, will my crash report continues to show up on Firebase with current configuration?

Could someone give me a solution/answer for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Firebase & Fabric here. I updated my other answer. That notice is only for the Fabric mobile apps available on the Play and App Stores. It does not affect the Fabric dashboard, Beta, or any other products. Your Crashlytics data in Fabric will continue to be processed until mid-2019 when Fabric is retired.

Once you link between Fabric and Firebase, data will flow into both dashboards. In early 2019, we plan on releasing a new SDK that is streamlined. Once you update to that future SDK, it will have the Fabric parts of the SDK removed which will make it smaller, but will then only send data to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks Mike, so what I should do now that I will link between Fabric and Firebase to continue follow Fabric Crashlytic on AppStore after Nov 30, then in early 2019, I will upgrade new SDK (re-submit to Appstore) and I can continue follow my Crashlytic with old and new data on Firebase Crashlytics. Is that right?

Comment: I think there is still some confusion. The Fabric mobile apps will stop working after November 30th. The Fabric dashboard and SDKs will continue to work through mid 2019. If you link to Firebase now, you will start pushing Crashlytics data to Firebase in addition to Fabric. Once the new SDKs are released and you ship an update, data would only flow into Firebase. If you've already linked, you would have data (old and new) in Firebase.

Comment: @MikeBonnell For those of us still using Fabric to integrate Crashlytics, should we now switch to the new SDK? I've already connected Fabric to Firebase and am receiving crash information in both dashboards. I'm just wondering if it's now safe to use the new SDK.

Comment: @JeremyHicks the Firebase Crashlytics SDK hasn't been released yet that would be Firebase only.

Comment: @MikeBonnell by when can we expect the updated SDK. Because instead of linking now Fabric to Firebase what if we link after releasing the new SDK?

Comment: I don't have an ETA to share on the SDK. If you link now, data will flow to both platforms. If you wait to install the new SDK, then data will only flow into Firebase.