# Migrate from Fabric to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-fabric

I try to migrate from Fabric to Firebase and I want to know how to link my application users to Firebase? In Fabric I used `Crashlytics.setUserName` what is the equivalent method in Firebase?

Comment: there is no different see this link : https://proandroiddev.com/migrating-crashlytics-to-the-firebase-console-5e05b6ff8c12

Comment: I saw this link but the migration steps in Fabric website is different, it forces me to remove fabric dependencies. check this link: https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/cannonball/ what about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Fabric's Crashlystic data to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49725108/migrate-fabrics-crashlystic-data-to-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Firebase here. The closest method to `Crashlytics.setUserName` is `Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("TheUserId");`.